# Why can I access the API from a browser but not wget?

Tags: support, api

If I try to access the following from firefox everything works even if I'm not logged in

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/19068?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow

However

```
wget http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/19068?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow
```

gives

```
Resolving api.stackexchange.com... 64.34.119.12
Connecting to api.stackexchange.com|64.34.119.12|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2012-05-08 01:46:49 ERROR 400: Bad Requ
```

Why do I get an error message?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to quote that URL.

```
wget 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0...&site=stackoverflow'
     ^                                                      ^
```

(And note that the payload is gzip-compressed.)

Comment: For technical reference, this happens because the `&` in the URL signifies to the shell to start a new background process and run the code following that.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the `&` characters in the URL. In most shells, `foo & bar` means "start running `foo` in the background while running `bar` in the foreground". Put quotes around the URL to make sure it gets passed as a single parameter to `wget`.